# Arrow pointing to body of text in a math environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, arrow-curve

I have the following problem. How can I get arrows in an align environment and how individual terms are framed? I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: You can try with the package witharrows: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/witharrows/witharrows.pdf

Answer (score 2):

A short example using `witharrows` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}

$\begin{WithArrows}
A &=  B \Arrow{explanation1} \\
& = D\Arrow{explanation2}\\
&=F\Arrow{explanation3}\\
&=K
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your help. One more thing. How ca I get individual terms framed?

Comment: I have not understood the phrase "How can I get individual terms framed?"